# How to use a string value in run time in SelectToken JSONPath query

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I have the following code and I am using popular Newtonsoft library in C#

```
string json = {
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "student 1",
      "grades": [
        {
          "subject1": "A",
          "subject2": "B"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

JObject rootJObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

I want to pick a particular student object. If I query using JSONPath with literal string like below, I am getting the actual object

`rootJObject.SelectToken("$.students[?(@.name=='student 1')]");`

Now If I want to pass the query string in run time, like below

`string studentName = "student 1";
rootJObject.SelectToken($"$.students[?(@.name=={studentName})]");`

It's throwing an exception like `"Unexpected character while parsing path query: s"`

Is it a limitation that we can use literal string only with single quotes in JSONPath query and not a string value in run time?

Comment: You need the single quotes around `{studentName}`, it should be `'{studentName}'`

Comment: Thanks @dbc, it worked.

Comment: @dbc You should submit an answer, it will be helpful for others coming to this question and Rajaraman please accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [Querying JSON with JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm), you need to put single quotes around string literals in filter expressions.  So `{studentName}` should be `'{studentName}'`:

```
var result = rootJObject.SelectToken($"$.students[?(@.name=='{studentName}')]");
```

Or, using the old [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.1) style:

```
var result = rootJObject.SelectToken(string.Format("$.students[?(@.name=='{0}')]", studentName));
```

Or with simple string concatenations:

```
var result2 = rootJObject.SelectToken("$.students[?(@.name=='" + studentName + "')]");
```

Note that "string literal" does not mean "a string constructed entirely at compile time", it means "string value included in a [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression."  Any c# string constructed by any method can be passed in.  In each statement above a string is being constructed in run-time by surrounding the value of the `studentName` variable with single quotes and embedding it in a full JSONPath expression.  The first statement uses [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) while the second uses an explicit function call, but both do the same thing.

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5WRaxG).